# como realizar upload de arquivo para servidor FTP no Python?

Tags: python, file-upload, sftp

Tenho um script que gera um arquivo em CSV e salva com o nome da data atual. Estou tentando fazer um script que verifique o arquivo mais recente criado e envie para o servidor FTP.

Como posso fazer isso?

Meu script abaixo:

```
import pysftp 
import datetime 
import os 
import glob

myHostname = 'sftp' 
myUsername = 'user' 
myPassword = 'password'

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts() cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts=r'C:\Users\Thiago Simas.ssh\known_hosts')

sftp = pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts)

list_of_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\ThiagoSimas\PycharmProjects\pythonProject*.csv') # para puxar todos os arquivos csv 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime) # para pegar o ultimo arquivo na pasta

localFilePath = latest_file 
remoteFilePath = '/Teste/

sftp.put(localFilePath, remoteFilePath)
sftp.close()
```

Comment: Falta fechar as aspas no remoteFilePath.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score -2):

reference [link aqui](https://techexpert.tips/pt-br/python-pt-br/python-upload-de-arquivo-para-o-servidor-ftp/)

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("192.168.2.222")
ftp.login("test", "123qwe")
localfile='/tmp/test.txt'
remotefile='test.txt'
with open(localfile, "rb") as file:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % remotefile, file)
```

read file in ftp

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("192.168.2.222")
ftp.login("test", "123qwe")
print("Directory: {}".format(ftp.pwd()))
ftp.retrlines("LIST")
ftp.quit()
```